# Copy only one column from many text files and create a single new file with tab separated new columns using Python or Bash

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, sed, awk

I have many files with the following structures in each:

FileOne:

```
1 x
2 r
3 f
4 t
: :
: :
1000 k
```

SecondFile:

```
1 x
2 r
3 f
4 t
: :
: :
1000 k
```

There are hundreds of files like this.
*I need a final output file as tab separated second column of each file*:

OutputFile:

```
x ..More Columns ... q
r ..... w
f ..... e
t ..... l
:       :
:       :
```

I will prefer to use Python or Bash Script.
Sorry for this silly question.

Here,s the progress I have so far, Created a list of * separated strings for the second coloumn of each file.
But **not generating Ideas how to write them**
Code:

```
import tkinter.filedialog
def FileToString (fin):
    Result = ''
    for line in fin:
        LineList = line.strip().split(' ')
        Result = Result + '*' + LineList[1]
return (Result)


File = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(title='Select the Files you want>> >>> >> >>>>')
Filenames = File.split()
Result = []
ArrayResult = []
OutPutFileName = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Select or Enter Output File >>     >>>> >>>>')
fout = open(OutPutFileName,'w')
for name in Filenames:
    fin = open(name,'r')
    FileResult = FileToString(fin)
    ArrayResult.append(FileResult)
```

Thanks

Comment: try out the `csv` module http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html  When you get stuck come back ;)

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: @p.in4matics Although this is a valid question, you are being downvoted because it does not show any research effort at tall

Comment: @RandyHoward I pasted the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
{ a[FNR] = a[FNR] (NR==FNR?"":"\t") $2 }
END{ for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i] }
' file1 file2 file3 ....
```

Answer (score 3):

At command line...

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
```

Here is my source: [Lesser-known Linux commands: join, paste, and sort](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/lesser-known-linux-commands-join-paste-and-sort/5031653)

If this isn't what you're looking for please reply and I'll work on it.

---

Try this out...  change the "file*" and "out.txt" to what you need them to be.

```
#!/bin/sh
outFile=out.txt
tmpFile=$$.tmp
for FILE in `ls file*`
do
    if [ ! -f ${tmpFile} ]; then
        # Need to seed the tmp file one first pass
        cp ${FILE} ${tmpFile}
        continue
    fi
    paste ${tmpFile} ${FILE} > ${outFile}
    mv ${outFile} ${tmpFile}
done
# Move the tmp file to output file
mv ${tmpFile} ${outFile}
```

Comment: Thanks, But what if I have plethora of Files.

Comment: Seems to also work even if you have different numbers of lines in the files.